# Xamarin forms - Picker Renderer set 'spinner' font size

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do you change the font of the 'spinner' portion of the picker? I can change the display font doing the following

```
public class MyPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {

        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            **Control.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(8);**
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible at least it's not subclassing the `PickerRenderer` defined in Xamarin.Forms for iOS.

The `UIPickerView` control that is displayed is marked as [private](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/PickerRenderer.cs#L12) for the renderer implementation, hence it will not be accesible from the subclass.

You could anyway do your own implementation of the Renderer and for this you could follow the implementation made by Xamarin.Forms ([here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/PickerRenderer.cs) you can see it) and do the modifications you need.

You will also need to subclass the `UIPickerView` class and override the `ViewFor` and there set the font size you want for the items..

Hope this helps.-